# The regular representation of $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a $F$-algebra, for all $a \in A$,

$$L_a : A \longrightarrow A \quad L_a (x) = ax$$
$$L_ab =L_a L_b \quad a, b \in A$$
$$L_{\lambda a + \mu b}  = \lambda L_a + \mu L_b $$

The  homomorphism $a\mapsto L_a$ from $A$ into $EndF(A)$ is called **the regular representation of $A$.**

> Can we say :" The regular representation is injective, unless $aA = 0$ for some nonzero $a \in A$"?
>
> Let $A$ be unital algebra , **Is the regular representation injective?**
>
> Is $A$ subfield $EndF(A)$?

Comment: Well, what it means for that representation *not* to be injective? That there is some nonzero $a\in A$ such that its image $L_a$ is zero, that is, the zero map $A\to A$.

Comment: As for your second question: if the algebra is unital, does there exist a nonzero $a\in A$ such that $aA=0$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for first question**: the zero element in $End_{F}(A)$ is the constantly zero map $A\to A$ sending all elements $x\in A$ to $0\in A$. For $a\in A$ such that $aA=0$ (i.e. $ax=0$ for all $x\in A$), what is the map "multiplication by $a$" from $A$ in itself? Conversely, what is the negation for $a\in A$ of the condition $aA=0$? It is: there is some $x\in A$ such that $ax\neq 0$. So is the corresopnding "multiplication by $a$" map from $A$ in itself the zero map?

**Hint for second question**: by definition $A$ is unital if there is some element $1\in A$ such that $1 x=x$ for all $x\in A$. Now use the conclusion you got from the first question: can there be an $a\in A$ which is not zero such that $ax=0$ for all $x\in A$?